# Finding all checked boxes in spreadsheet and adding rows to email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to put together a script for one of our user and am not getting anywhere fast. They currently have a button at the top of their Google spreadsheet that when clicked it emails another user for them to check the spreadsheet. There is a column of checkboxes(column K) that the second user looks through for a checked box, get the info they need and then unchecks the box. The problem is that they are getting up to about 600 rows which can take a good bit of time to find the checked box/boxes since any of them could be checked(usually only 1 or 2 of them are changed at a time). My idea would be to put the row of all checked boxes in either the subject or the message of the email sent. I have tried to find similar scripts online to pick apart to get this working but have yet to find anything that accomplishes this. I am not to familiar with google scripting since I do not use it often but wanted to try to help this user out. Below is the very simple script that is triggered when the button is pressed to email the second user. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var emailAddress = "users@email.com"
    var message = "*Link to spreadsheet second user needs to check*"
    var subject = "New Job Tickets Entered";\\I would like the row of the checked back to be in the subject of the email sent if possible.
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  Browser.msgBox('Emails sent to user');
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sendChecked() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  const startRow=2;
  const subject="Checked Rows"
  const recipient="users@email.com";
  let n=0;
  let body='These are the rows that were checked'
  let html='These are the rows that were checked';
  const cbs=sh.getRange(startRow,1,sh.getLastRow()-startRow+1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  cbs.forEach((r,i)=>{
    if(r[10]==true) {
      html+='<br />' + r[12];//just send column M
      body+='\n'+r[12];
      sh.getRange(i+startRow,11).setValue(false);
      n++;
    }
  });
  if(n)GmailApp.sendEmail(recipient,subject,body,{htmlBody:html})
}
```

Comment: The output in the email looks to find the right row but is just dumping all cell values from said row. Thank you for getting me so much closer. Below if the output I get.

`true,Mon Jan 04 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),DS,false,12564,01 CANTON,,Fri Jan 01 2021 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time),PLACE 171,link,true,,2,,,,,,(The commas continue a few hundred times.)`

Comment: I will look in to how to do this. If I can separate the "M" column(This is a column for job numbers) and remove the excess commas I should be able to make this work. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: I was able to remove the commas but I'm still having trouble figuring out how to isolate the column using the the .map method.

Comment: So as I understand it you just want column M from each row.  Is that correct?

Comment: Okay that should do it and please note I had an error in the first version so take the entire script.  I had the last parameter in the getRange() as getLastRow() when it should have been getLastColumn() and you could take less data if you wanted to and then modify the subscripts but I was just taking the easy way out.